# JAX-RS - JSON without root node on Glassfish 3.2

Tags: java, json, jaxb, glassfish, jax-rs

Exactly the same question has been asked here: 
[JAX-RS - JSON without root node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838192/jax-rs-json-without-root-node)
But the solution doesn't work for me because my server doesn't have any other interfaces besides REST, thus file WEB-INF/web.xml doesn't exists.
Below is the original question:

I have a restfull webservice, and the response is:

```
{
    "cities": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "City 01",
            "state": "A1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "City 02",
            "state": "A1"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I want this

```
    [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "City 01",
            "state": "A1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "City 02",
            "state": "A1"
        }
    ]
```

How I can configure JAX-RS to produces JSON without root node using only JAX-RS feature, and not implementation specific feature? My code needs to be portable accross any appserver.

Thanks

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027713/unwrap-a-element-in-jackson-jaxb)

Comment: 1) JAX-RS is a REST framework, it doesn't know or care about JSON 2) Your second example is invalid JSON and will be rejected by pretty much every JSON library out there.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the link. I have already tried it and it has no effect. But if I call rootUnwrapping(false) then I get 2 wrappers. See this for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199453/how-can-i-customize-serialization-of-a-list-of-jaxb-objects-to-json

Comment: The accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199453/how-can-i-customize-serialization-of-a-list-of-jaxb-objects-to-json also refers to web.xml which I don't have as mentioned above.

Comment: @Perception Yes, you are right, I have copied it from the other post and it had an extra pair braces. I have fixed the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally solved the problem. All I had to do is to mark the checkbox "Package" in
Project Properties/Compile/GlassFish Server 3+ Jersay