# Outputting JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs

I am trying to output a list in JSON formatting but it's not coming out quite the way I want it.

Here is the output:

```
{
    "songMap": [
        {
            "SID": "699",
            "SDID": "1079287588763212246"
        },
        {
            "SID": "700",
            "SDID": "1079287588763212221"
        },
        {
            "SID": "701",
            "SDID": "1079287588763212230"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is what I would like it to look like:

```
[
        {
            "SID": "699",
            "SDID": "1079287588763212246"
        },
        {
            "SID": "700",
            "SDID": "1079287588763212221"
        },
        {
            "SID": "701",
            "SDID": "1079287588763212230"
        }
]
```

I don't need nor want the intermediate array, im not sure why it's being added.  I have a custom class as follows:

```
public class songID {
    public int SID;
    public String SDID;

    public songID() {}

    public songID(int key, String value) {
        this.SID  = key;
        this.SDID = value;
    }
}
```

This is how it's being serialized:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(songMap);
```

If I print out the string json ,it looks the way I want it to.  However the server is adding the additional "SongMap."  Here is how my variable is declared at the top of the class:

```
private List<songID> songMap;
.....
songMap = new ArrayList<songID>();
```

Comment: songMap itself, which contains many songID objects

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAX-RS - JSON without root node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838192/jax-rs-json-without-root-node)

Comment: There seem to be (non-portable) ways to configure JAX-RS to not do that (see the linked other question), but if you control the client, too, it is probably easier to just unwrap the response on the client.

Comment: @Thilo thank you for the link, it's not a huge deal, I can just manage it on the client, just thought it was curious behavior.  If you create an answer with this solution/link, I will give you credit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not serializing the `List` directly but a container having the `List` named as `songMap`. (Confusing name choice by the way.) If you serialize the `List` directly it comes out fine as shown below.

```
songMap = new ArrayList<songID>();
songMap.add(new songID(699, "1079287588763212246"));
songMap.add(new songID(700, "1079287588763212221"));

GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gb.setPrettyPrinting().create();

System.out.println(gson.toJson(songMap));
```

*Output :*

```
[
  {
    "SID": 699,
    "SDID": "1079287588763212246"
  },
  {
    "SID": 700,
    "SDID": "1079287588763212221"
  }
]
```

Comment: Right, I receive that response when I print out gson as I mentioned above, the problem comes when the server sends the response.  I get the above output when analyzing it with Fiddler.

Comment: What you probably need is `gson.toJson(serverResponse.getSongMap());` instead of serializing `serverResponse` directly. That's psuedo-code by the way. I would need to see your code to be exact.